# How to set a formula using VBA in an Excel cell?

Tags: vba, formula

I want to write the formula =IF(D7,B7,"") using VBA,

Using "=IF(D7,B7,"")", or '=IF(D7,B7,"")', or "=IF(D7,B7,'')" does not  work.  I have read that using double quotes is OK, but it does not seem to work for me.

```
   Sub SetFormula()
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet1").Activate
       Sheets("sheet1").Range("B4").Select
       Range("B4").FormulaLocal = "=IF(D5,B5,'')"   'Errors out 
   End Sub
```

I'd like to write the formula to the cell.

Comment: change `''` to `""""`

Comment: Tnx.  That does it!

Comment: FYI you can use `Formula` here in place of `FormulaLocal`, since you're using the "default" comma separator.  You'd use `FormulaLocal` if you wanted to use some other separator such as ";"

Comment: I'd like to translate that into:

Answer (score 0):

Don't `Activate` the sheet, or `Select` a range.

If the sheet "Sheet1" exists in `ThisWorkbook` at compile-time, then it has a code name identifier that you can use in code to refer to that particular worksheet object - default would be `Sheet1`, but you can change that in the *Properties* toolwindow (F4) by modifying the value of the `(Name)` property.

Single quotes and double quotes each serve a specific purpose, and are not interchangeable. Problem is, you're inside a VBA string literal that's already delimited with `"` double quotes, so it needs to be *escaped*; the way to do this in VBA, is to double it up `""`, like so:

```
Sheet1.Range("B4").Formula = "=IF(D5,B5,"""")"
```